# ffmpeg created video receiving error message on Youtube

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube

I am using this command to generate a video with a cover page and an audio.

ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 1 -i c:/temp/coverImage.jpeg -i C:/temp/out/input.mp3 -vf "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2" -c:a copy -shortest -c:v libx264 C:/temp/VideoOut/output.mp4

But the generated video got an error message from Youtube after it is uploaded.

"Your video has an unsupported aspect ratio"

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Published video can be seen but not able to add End Screen.

Comment: not sure if this helps, but in this [entry on Quora](https://qr.ae/prkl9I) says: `At last, please note, your video has to be at least 25 seconds long to have an ‘end screen’.`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My video is about 16 minutes.